# Is Grooveshark Javascript API still functional?

Tags: javascript, api, grooveshark

Does anyone know if the Grooveshark Javascript API is still functional?

The API in question is this one: http://grooveshark.com/GroovesharkAPI.html

I google'd everywhere and cannot find a solution or direct answer to this question.

Cheers.

EDIT: I tried the API and I can't get it to work. Thus was wondering if the anyone knows if the examples are outdated or if the support for this functionality is no more.

Comment: I did and it didn't work. Just wondering if I was implementing it wrong or if it is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

It is still functional, tried it just now.
Example: `alert(window.Grooveshark.getCurrentSongStatus().song.songName);`

To test you can run it in firefox's web console or as a greasemonkey script.